# Does CartoDB support alphabets other than Latin?

Tags: carto, encoding, internationalization

Does anyone know if CartoDB supports alphabets other than Latin? I'm trying to upload some data with Cyrillic characters but have had no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should support cyrillic as long as the original data is properly encoded. To make sure you can import your data into QGIS or a similar software, see if characters look good (if they don't then you can try setting different encodings when you import) and then export it using csISLatinCyrillic.

I've successfully imported tables with this encoding in SHP, CSV and ODT formats, and fixed prblems using the above mentioned method. Haven't tried other formats though.