# Does cartodb support arabic text?

Tags: carto, internationalization, arabic

I'd like to use Arabic text in my map.

I saw this post earlier about Cyrillic text ([Does CartoDB support alphabets other than Latin?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/81899/does-cartodb-support-alphabets-other-than-latin)), but does anyone know about Arabic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tested this and it looks like CartoDB does fine with Arabic. See http://cholmes.cartodb.com/tables/arabic_map/public/map

Though I can't read Arabic, and am not sure about the right to left stuff, so may be a bit off.